# Can you limit the scope of a TypeScript global type?

Tags: typescript, jestjs, tsconfig

Our team has configured TypeScript to make the `jest` types available globally:

```json
// tsconfig.json
{
  ...,
  "types": ["jest", "@testing-library/jest-dom", ...]
}
```

This is really nice for `*.test.ts` files, but today I realized that it also accepts `jest` (and related functions) in regular old `*.ts` files—which makes sense after I read up on the [tsconfig docs](https://www.typescriptlang.org/tsconfig#types).  Is it possible to limit the availability of a type (`jest` in our case) to a certain directory or subset of files?

```js
// component.tsx (error - 'jest' should not be defined)
const mockFn = jest.fn();

// component.test.tsx (no error - 'jest' should be defined)
const mockFn = jest.fn();
```

Comment: If the jest types are coming from the library itself, then no I don't think so. If you had declared the global types yourself, I think you would be able to put the type defs file in the same directory as your jest tests (if they are all centralized) to limit scope. But if your test files are scattered and/or co-located with components, I don't think there is a way to limit global type scope by filename.