# Use jest's expect.extend() with TypeScript scoped to a single test file

Tags: typescript, jestjs

This question is similar to [Can you limit the scope of a TypeScript global type?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66572622/can-you-limit-the-scope-of-a-typescript-global-type) but a little different (though I would love an answer to it, as well).

In Jest, I want to do something like:

```ts
declare global {
  namespace jest {
    interface Matchers<R> {
      toBeAwesome(this: Matchers<void, HTMLElement>): R;
    }
  }
}

export {};

expect.extend({
  toBeAwesome() {
    // ...
  }
});
```

However, I only call `extend` in that specific file, and therefore I do not want other test files to be able to access it.  The `declare global {}` bit seems to screw me over.

I've also tried something hacky:

```ts
declare const expect: jest.Expect & {
  <T = any>(actual: T): jest.JestMatchers<T> & {
    toBeSelected(this: jest.Matchers<void, HTMLElement>): void;
  };
};
```

But the method won't even show up.

I also tried directly declaring `namespace jest` outside of the global scope, but since `jest` is a global namespace, it created a new namespace instead of augmenting the other.

Is it possible to scope an augmentation to a specific file and any file that imports it?

Answer (score 2):

I don't think you can limit the scope of an augmented type within the same package, but you could define your own expect function with the type you want:

Something like:

```js
function expectElement(actual: HTMLEelement): ElementExpect {
  return expect(actual) as any as ElementExpect
}

type ElementExpect = JestExpect & ElementMatchers

interface ElementMatchers<R = void> extends Matchers<void> {
  toBeSelected(): R
}
```

Then, arguably your tests are more explicit:

```
it("should be awesome", () => {
  expectElement(el).toBeAwesome()
})
```

Comment: Interesting.  It's kind of annoying that you have to use a separate variable name.  I wonder if you could `import { expect as _expect } from 'jest';` and then `const expect = _expect as typeof _expect & { ... };`.

Answer (score 0):

Another workaround if you're using explicit imports from `@jest/globals` (rather than `@types/jest` which makes the globals available to TS everywhere) is to modify the type of the imported version of `expect`.

```
import { expect as _expect } from '@jest/globals';

const expect = _expect as unknown as {
  <T = unknown>(actual: T): {
    toBeAwesome(): void;
  } & ReturnType<typeof _expect>;
} & typeof _expect;
```

As written (there might be a better way), this doesn't provide type verification for the actual thing passed to `expect()`, but it at least makes the matcher available and limited to the current file.

You could also do this with global types (`@types/jest`) by redeclaring `expect` with a different name, e.g. `const expectElement = expect as unknown as /* custom type */`.